# Can we group a set of values and determine a flag if a condition is met only once?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm not trying to flag a value if the condition is met at least once. The code here is not what i'm trying to do.

```
Flag = 
IF(CALCULATE(CONTAINS('Table','Table'[Value],"7"),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Group]))
,1,0)
```

I'm trying to get a flag for only when 7 shows up once.

```
Group|Value|
A        7
A        2
A        3
B        8
B        9
C        7
C        5
C        7
D        7
```

I want it to give me this result

```
Group|Value|Result
A        7    N
A        2    N
A        3    N
B        8    N
B        9    N
C        7    N
C        5    N
C        7    N
D        7    Y
```

Note that only in D does 7 show up once. Otherwise it is not valid.

Comment: Doesn't 7 only show up once for A too?

Comment: No because 2 and 3 show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
Result = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Group])) = 1 && 'Table'[Value] = 7, 
    "Y", 
    "N"
)
```